# How to parse access.log (apache ) with Python and argparse

Tags: python-3.x

I've got some task: to parse log file (access.log) with python and write results of parsing into json-file.
This is example of line in access.log:

109.169.248.247 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100] "POST /administrator/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4494 "http://almhuette-raith.at/administrator/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" 4374

And there is  my code:

```
  import argparse
  import json
  import re

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='apache_logparser')
parser.add_argument('-f', dest='logfile', action='store', default='access.log')
args = parser.parse_args()
    
    def all_req():
        reg_ip = (r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")
        with open(args.logfile) as file:
            for index, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
                try:
                    ip = len(re.findall(reg_ip, line))
                    return (f"Requests Summary: {ip}")
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
    
    with open("final_log.json", "w") as jsonfile:
        json.dump(all_req(), jsonfile, indent=4)
```

When the code is executed, the sum of requests in json-file is listed as '1', but in fact, there are more than 3,000,000 requests in my access.log.I can't figure out how to edit the code to get the sum of all requests. I would be grateful for your help

Comment: Your return statement immediately exits the function on the first matching line. Also, you're not summing anything here, only taking the length of the first match in the first line

Comment: In any case, if the server logs are not corrupted in some way, you don't need to capture the IP with patterns, as that's always the first column, so `line.split(" ", 1)` would get you that

Comment: Thank уou, but I really don't quite understand how the code should look like with line.split(' ',1)

Comment: `ip, _ = line.split(" ", 1)`, but obviously that isn't going to help you parse the entire line, but neither is the code you've shown

Comment: If you literally want the number of requests, that's simply the length of the file `return sum(1 for line in open(args.logfile))`

Comment: Otherwise, Filebeat + Elasticsearch +  Kibana is really more suited for log analysis than Python code, and there's pre-built log parsers for it